# How to insert unique id's for pre inserted records in mysql

Tags: mysql, function, procedure

I have a table which has around five thousands records already inserted,and i want to insert a unique id for each record. how can i do this. please help.

Comment: First write what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply add the key column using `AUTO_INCREMENT` - that way, the IDs will be generated automatically.

```
ALTER TABLE `users` ADD `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just go to structure tab and press change and give it unique

- If it has duplicates ,apply a query based on your structure(I dont know your table structure) and again repeat the above step

Answer (score 0):

You just alter the table add a new column and make it primary, not null and auto increment and this will do the work

```
ALTER TABLE `employee` ADD `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
```